# Prove that set of all finite subsets of N with n elements is denumerable

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

I need to prove that the set S of all finite subsets of ℕ with exactly  *n* elements (where  *n* is a natural number) is denumerable. I think I need to set up an injection from S to ℕ since ℕ is a countable set but am not sure how exactly to describe that 1-1 mapping? I understand the proof of the set of all finite sets being denumerable but I'm just struggling when you specify that the cardinality of the finite sets has to be  *n*.

Comment: One approach among many: For two elements, $\{0,1\},\{0,2\},\{1,2\},\{0,3\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{0,4\},\{1,4\},\{2,4\},\{3,4\},\{0,5\},\dots$.  Can you formalize this?  Can you generalize this to $n>2$, more than two elements at a time?

Comment: A subset of a denumerable set is denumerable, right, mathhelp?